# Drag and Drop functionality in my graphic - Dialog Based MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a dialog based MFC application that reads the coordinates of height and radius from a text file and displays it as a plot of points on a picture control window. Now, after the points have been plotted I need to be able to drag and drop a point to any particular location in the window in order for me to have the points coordinates changed to its new location. All this should be done by dragging and dropping it with my right click button. I do understand that the event that I should be using would be OnRButtonDown() and OnRButtonUp(), but I am unable to understand as how to include the drag and drop feature in my application. For your information, I have done the plotting of points, I just need to understand the implementation of dragging and dropping feature.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things for drag & drop:

1. In OnRButtonDown(), you need to identify the point you'd pick up, set the RButtonDown flag to true.
2. Check the flag and if true, post paint message to draw the plot dynamically per the new position of the point in OnMouseMove(), to make it as smooth as possible (not flashing), do not invalidate all but invalidate and redraw a certain region.
3. In OnRButtonUp(), update the flag to false.

You might also need to use [SetCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646262%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)/[ReleaseCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646261%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in your OnRButtonDown()/OnRButtonUp() for the cases that you dragging and moving the mouse out of your dialog window.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brandon. Was really helpful. It worked after I implemented what you said.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to inherit from `CWnd` or `CStatic` and do the painting yourself. And then when dragging is being done, you need to move the drawing object by yourself. Working with Device Context (`CDC`, `CClientDC`) would come into picture. You need to use `CDC::SetROP2` and other methods to draw graphics objects.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out as to how to get this working. So, in case people want to know how to implement this in their programs can get an idea from this code.

Code:

```
void CRangemasterGeneratorDlg::OnRButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

    GetCursorPos(&point);

    int mx = point.x;
    int my = point.y;

    float cursR, cursH;

    cursR = (mx - 312) / 7.2;// records the current cursor's radius(x) position
    cursH = (641 - my) / 5.3;// records the current cursor's height(y) position

    CString Hgt,Rds;
    Hgt.Format("%.3f",cursH);// Rounding off Height values to 3 decimal places
    Rds.Format("%.3f",cursR);// Rounding off Radius values to 3 decimal places

    curR = (float)atof(Rds);
    curH = (float)atof(Hgt);

    // I had limits on my grid from 0 - 100 on both x and y-axis
        if(curR < 0 || curR >100 || curH < 0 || curH > 100)  
        return;

    SetCapture();

    SetCursor(::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_CROSS));

    //snap the point, compare the point with your array and save position on 'y'
    for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      if(curH < m_Points[i+1].m_height_point && curH >m_Points[i-1].m_height_point)
        {
            curH = m_Points[i].m_height_point;
            curR = m_Points[i].m_radius_point;
            y = i;
        }
    }

    CDialog::OnRButtonDown(nFlags, point);
    UpdateData(false);
    Invalidate();
}

void CRangemasterGeneratorDlg::OnRButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    ReleaseCapture();

    GetCursorPos(&point);

    int mx1 = point.x;
    int my1 = point.y;

    float curR1,curH1;

    curR1 = (mx1 - 312) / 7.2;// records the current cursor's radius(x) position
    curH1 = (641 - my1) / 5.3;// records the current cursor's height(y) position

    m_Points[y].m_radius_point = curR1;
    m_Points[y].m_height_point = curH1;

    Invalidate();

    CDialog::OnRButtonUp(nFlags, point);
    UpdateData(false);
}
```

...

I have ran this code and it works brilliantly well. The variables in this code are pertaining to the ones that I have used in my program. In case you don't understand, feel free to ask me.